# Generate specific date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have to generate date in specific format in javascript, The required format is "**2017-12-07T14:47:00+0530**". I have tried using moments but got stuck in time zone field.

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');  //output 2018-03-06T14:32:45+05:30
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I guarantee you this has been asked and answered, if you [search](/help/searching).

Comment: Just by reading the docs `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

You want the `ZZ` timezone format rather than a single `Z`.

```js
console.log(new moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ')) 
// 2018-03-06T09:14:44+0000
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```